# Lagged variable(s) with random/fixed effects

Tags: regression, mixed-model, econometrics, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am running a regression on unbalanced panel data where I lagged by a timestep some of the explanatory variables. I also included an interaction effect between a lagged variable and a non-lagged variable. I wanted to ask if there is any possible problem that could arise that I need to be aware of while using a random/fixed effect model in the estimation.

Comment: To be clear, this is **not** a lagged version of your outcome?

Comment: No no it's not the dependent variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incorporating a lead and/or lag of your **in**dependent variable(s) in panel data contexts (e.g., fixed effects estimation) is generally not a problem. On the other hand, incorporating a lag of your *dependent* variable on the right-hand side of your equation will compromise consistency. The differenced/demeaned residual is necessarily correlated with your lagged outcome.

Thus, feel free to adjust the time configuration of your **in**dependent variables as you see fit. Just be aware that it doesn’t necessarily absolve you of all endogeneity concerns. This [paper](https://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/62350/1/MPRA_paper_62350.pdf) is a good treatise on where “lag identification” is often used inappropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Please read https://www.scielo.br/j/rbgn/a/gPYpsvqrBQKDLgLqH8LHNPz/?lang=en&format=pdf, which makes Monte Carlo simulations to see what happens when you include a lagged dependend variable on the panel data regression.

In short, you shoudn't use OLS, fixed effects or random effects in this case. Use Sys-GMM or D-GMM.