# Firm fixed effect with lagged dependent variable

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

Let $r_{it}$ be the asset return at time $t$ of company $i$. Now consider this model:
$$
r_{it} = \alpha_t + \delta r_{i,t-1} + \beta \, \text{Size} + \lambda T + \gamma_\text{TEC} + \varepsilon_{it}
$$
where:

- $\alpha_t$ represents year fixed effects;
- $\text{Size}$ is the logarithm of the market capitalization of firm $i$ at time $t$;
- $T$ is the logarithm of a linear trend ($1, 2, \dots$)
- $\gamma_\text{TECH}$ is a dummy variable that takes value 1 when the firm is a technological company, 0 otherwise;

Including a firm fixed effect in a model that already includes a lagged dependent variable can lead to biased estimates. The reason for this bias is that the firm fixed effect is correlated with the lagged dependent variable, leading to an endogeneity problem (see. [Lagged variable(s) with random/fixed effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/497895/lagged-variables-with-random-fixed-effects)) Do you suggest any solution?

Comment: Arellano-Bond is useful here.